# How do I add an on-delay animation and scoreboard to this little game I made

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created this color guessing game from scratch using HTML, CSS and JS. You're given a random RGB value and you guess which out of three given colors is the correct one. Now I want to take it a step higher by adding a scoreboard and score (Which I'm not sure how to do at all) and a full-screen congratulation message when you guess the color right. I've tried doing that but the animation doesn't seem to work.

HTML

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <h1 class="text-centered" id="main-h1">Guess The Color!</h1>
    <h2 class="text-centered" id="colorguess"></h2>

    <p id="score">
        
    </p>

    <div class="box-container">
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bravo">
        <p id="bravo-text">
            BRAVO
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

CSS

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    font-family: arial;
    background-color: #1c1874;
    color: rgb(105, 105, 139);
    color: #fff;
}
.text-centered{
 text-align: center;  
 text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1); 
}
.box-container{
    padding: 200px;
    align-self: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content:space-evenly;
}
.box{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border:5px solid #ffffff;
    
}
#score{
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 2em;
    position: fixed;
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
}
#score::before {
    content: "Score: ";
  }
#bravo{
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    
  opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5em;
    background-color: rgba(4, 8, 97, 0.69);
}
#bravo-text{
    flex: 0 0 120px;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);
}
```

JS

```
function getrandomcolor(){
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    rgb = "rgb("+r+", "+g+", "+b+")";
    return rgb;
}
function gamestart(){
   var mainh1 = document.getElementById('main-h1');
   mainh1.innerHTML = "Guess the color!";
    rgbvaluetrue = getrandomcolor();
    var rgb = document.getElementById('colorguess');
    rgb.innerHTML = rgbvaluetrue;
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box');

    var scoreboard= document.getElementById('score');
    var score = 0;
    
    function displaybravo(element){
        var op= 0;
                var timer = setInterval(function () {
                    if (op >= 1){
                        clearInterval(timer);
                    }
                    if(op>=0.1){
                        element.style.display = "flex";
                        element.style.flexDirection = "column";
                        element.style.justifyContent = "center";
                        element.style.alignItems="center";
                    }
                    element.style.opacity = op;
                    element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
                    op += op * 0.1;
                }, 10);

    }

    for(var i=0;i<box.length;i++){
        box[i].style.backgroundColor = getrandomcolor();
    }

    //here I am trying to assign the initial rgb value to one of the divs randomly
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * box.length);
    
    box[rand].style.backgroundColor = rgbvaluetrue;
    //here I check if the div you clicked on is correct
    function markSelection() {
        if(this.style.backgroundColor == rgbvaluetrue) {
            mainh1.innerHTML="BRAVO";
            setTimeout(function() { 
                var brv = document.getElementById('bravo');
                displaybravo(brv);
                gamestart(); }, 2000);
        } else {
            gamestart();
        }
    }
    
    for(var i=0;i<box.length;i++){
        box[i].onclick = markSelection;
    }
   scoreboard.innerHTML=score;
}
gamestart();
```

Comment: There is another stack community called Game Development which may or may not also be helpful.

Comment:  I'm looking at things and the interval you set never clears, which is causing problems on my tiny little pc. Cool little game, this may be better suited for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but considering there are bugs / unintended action I think it may still be valid here. I will have a response for you after my lunch 

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed your game and made some changes to the code based on what stood out to me. There were a few bugs that were important to correct, and many things I changed purely for readability / preference.

I tend to avoid directly using timeouts. Promises are a good way to control the order of things in javascript. This game could likely benefit from OOP to make the logic more organized, but I didn't want to return you something that was completely unrecognizable. You are welcome to take this to code review for a more complete refactoring.

The first issue that I noticed is that your `setInterval` never resolves with the logic implemented. Because it never resolves, every time you attempted to show the bravo message, it would start an interval at 10 ms, and they would stack on top of eachother. This quickly would become an issue, potentially even breaking your page. Instead of attempting to redesign your interval logic, I decided to use the css `transition` attribute to handle the Bravo message, and I threw in a keyframe animation so you could see how to add other effects without javascript. Instead of having to write logic in js and preform resource expensive operations, I can leave the animation to css. Now js just needs to add and remove the hidden class.

I also wrote a helper function `wait` at the top of the js, and made functions with waiting async so I could use the `await` keyword instead of nesting my code inside timeouts. This is more readable in my own opinion.

To add a score, I moved the score variable above the `gameStart` function. This way each time the game restarts, the score is not affected. Then I just had to increment the score variable whenever a correct answer is given, and change the text in the dom.

One bug I noticed was that the correct answer could have been clicked several times, and the points would have increased, because the event listener was still active after the answer was submitted. To handle this, I changed the way the event listener was applied. Instead of using `element.onclick =`, I opted for `el.addEventListener("click",` . This allowed me to use `.removeEventListener` once the answer was given, and only reapply the event listener once the next round started. I also added a wait for incorrect answers, and some text when the wrong answer was given.

Other more cosmetic changes include using a helper function `$` to make grabbing elements easier, and changing `.innerHTML` to `.innerText` to more clearly show intent / prevent potential bugs.

I didn't correct it in this code, but it's worth mentioning variable names in javascript are usually camel case. i.e. instead of `getrandomcolor` it would be `getRandomColor`

If you have any questions about my code, please ask

```js
const wait = t => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, t));
const $ = (str, dom = document) => [...dom.querySelectorAll(str)];
function getrandomcolor(){
  const random255 = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  const [r, g, b] = Array.from({length: 3}, random255);
  return "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
}
let scoreboard = $('#score')[0];
let score = 0;
function gamestart(){
  var mainh1 = $('#main-h1')[0];
  mainh1.innerText = "Guess the color!";
  rgbvaluetrue = getrandomcolor();
  var rgb = $('#colorguess')[0];
  rgb.innerText = rgbvaluetrue;
  var body = document.body;
  var allBoxes = $('.box');

  async function displaybravo(element){
    element.classList.remove("hidden");
    await wait(2000);
    element.classList.add("hidden");
    await wait(1000);
  }

  for (var i=0; i<allBoxes.length; i++) {
    allBoxes[i].style.backgroundColor = getrandomcolor();
  }

  var randomBoxIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * allBoxes.length);
  allBoxes[randomBoxIndex].style.backgroundColor = rgbvaluetrue;

  async function markSelection() {
    allBoxes.forEach(box => box.removeEventListener("click", markSelection));
    if (this.style.backgroundColor == rgbvaluetrue) {
      score++;
      scoreboard.innerText = score;
      mainh1.innerText = "BRAVO";
      var brv = $('#bravo')[0];
      await displaybravo(brv);
      gamestart();
    } else {
      mainh1.innerText = "NOPE!";
      await wait(1000);
      gamestart();
    }
  }

  allBoxes.forEach(box => box.addEventListener("click", markSelection));
  scoreboard.innerHTML = score;
}
gamestart();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: arial;
  background-color: #1c1874;
  color: rgb(105, 105, 139);
  color: #fff;
}
.text-centered{
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);
}
.box-container{
  padding: 200px;
  align-self: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
}
.box{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border:5px solid #ffffff;

}
#score{
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 2em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
}
#score::before {
  content: "Score: ";
}
#bravo {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  height: 100%; /*needed to transition to / from*/

  transition: height 2s;
}
#bravo.hidden {
  height: 0;
}
#bravo-text {
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: bold;

  color: black;
  animation: glow 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes glow {
  from {
    text-shadow:
    0 0 5px #fff,
    0 0 10px #fff,
    0 0 15px #e60073,
    0 0 20px #e60073,
    0 0 25px #e60073,
    0 0 30px #e60073,
    0 0 35px #e60073;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow:
    0 0 10px #fff,
    0 0 20px #ff4da6,
    0 0 30px #ff4da6,
    0 0 40px #ff4da6,
    0 0 50px #ff4da6,
    0 0 60px #ff4da6,
    0 0 70px #ff4da6;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script defer src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <h1 class="text-centered" id="main-h1">Guess The Color!</h1>
  <h2 class="text-centered" id="colorguess"></h2>

  <p id="score">

  </p>

  <div class="box-container">
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bravo" class="hidden flexCenter">
    <p id="bravo-text" class="flexCenter">
      BRAVO
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```